# Move from a local single-user database to an online multi-user database

Tags: sql-server, database, share, multi-user

I have a calendar-type WPF program that is used to assign the workload to a team. The events are stored in an Access database and the program is accessed by one person at a time by remotely connection to a computer. The team has grown and multiple people would need to access the program simultaneously. I can install the program on several computers, but where should I move the database? On a software like Dropbox/Onedrive, on a SQL online host? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL Server on many Cloud platforms (though I am not sure Dropbox can host SQL Server natively). Azure (Microsoft cloud) is a very mature solution. You still should verify, now that multiple users will be managing data, that the database is backed up a regular basis and that any updates to data should be done within transactions that your code should be aware of. 'Aware of' means that if there is a conflict your code should either resubmit or notify the user that the insert/update/delete failed.